# Why it doesn't fade out?

Tags: jquery

Why it doesn't fade out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>asdasds</p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

my script.js is an external file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('p').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: Wow Interesting all are fine in your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/no7jydaw/  no wrong in code...Do u get any error?

Comment: URL http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js doesn't exist.

Comment: yes It just displays the text in firefox page ... how will I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Error 404** when i open in new tab

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js

Use below code in your script tag.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

or as per **kmsdev** suggested add newest version

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What library should I use?

Comment: Or use new 2.x version... `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis Please, mark the answer as valid if it solved your issue  

Comment: @JqueryKing the star ?

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis In this answer, just under vote score.